# Sqlite error include where clause can any one help me

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
SELECT contactPhoneID, contactName, contactNumber, contactNumberType,
  contactEmail, contactImage, contactSortKey, contactCountryCode,
  contactRingTone, contactStatus, contactTimeStamp, contactMoodName,
  contactMoodType, contactEmotiUserFlag, contactSpeedDialID,
  contactSpeedDialFlag, contactFavorites, GROUP_CONCAT(contactNumber) AS contactNumber,
  contactName
FROM CONTACT_TABLE
WHERE contactFavorites = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY contactPhoneID
```

hello getting error where clause adding beside this its working perfectly

Comment: I want to add WHERE contactFavorites = 'TRUE' but its not going through

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message here.

Comment: what type of column is contactFavorites?

Comment: What is the error message? Is this MySQL or SQLLite, What type is `contactFavorites`?

Comment: sqllite its string type

Answer (score 0):

To get your query to work properly, you need yo group by all non-aggregated columns:

```
SELECT contactPhoneID, contactName, contactNumber, contactNumberType,
  contactEmail, contactImage, contactSortKey, contactCountryCode,
  contactRingTone, contactStatus, contactTimeStamp, contactMoodName,
  contactMoodType, contactEmotiUserFlag, contactSpeedDialID,
  contactSpeedDialFlag, contactFavorites, GROUP_CONCAT(contactNumber) AS contactNumber,
  contactName
FROM CONTACT_TABLE
WHERE contactFavorites = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY contactPhoneID, contactName, contactNumber, contactNumberType,
  contactEmail, contactImage, contactSortKey, contactCountryCode,
  contactRingTone, contactStatus, contactTimeStamp, contactMoodName,
  contactMoodType, contactEmotiUserFlag, contactSpeedDialID,
  contactSpeedDialFlag, contactFavorites
```

MySQL supports non-standard grouping behaviour, whereby if you group by less than all non-aggregated columns, it will return one random row per unique group. AFAIK, all other DBs throw a syntax exception if you try this.

Comment: Both MySQL and SQLite support this; SQLite guarantees certain values when the group contains a single row or when MIN/MAX is used.